# Laravel 7 has('relation') with pagination slows down query

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have filter `Post::with('media')->has('media')->paginate(50)`
I have 350k rows in post table and 270k rows in media

I have index in media table `model_id` and `model_type` fields and posts table `published_at` field.

First query:

```
SELECT
    count(*) AS aggregate
FROM
    `posts`
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `media`
        WHERE
            `posts`.`id` = `media`.`model_id`
            AND `media`.`model_type` = 'App\Models\Post'
    )
```

Execute: 972ms

Second query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `posts`
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `media`
        WHERE
            `posts`.`id` = `media`.`model_id`
            AND `media`.`model_type` = 'App\Models\Post'
    )
    ORDER BY
        `published_at` DESC
    LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Execute: 1.7s

Comment: `paginate` will `select count(*)` for calculating the total number. maybe u can use simplePaginate instead.

Comment: Yes simplePaginate instead close this issue, but i need to known what is solution for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Count would only return **1 row**

and Your `select *` **50** that takes simply time.

and to check the difference between 2 querys try [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html)

```
EXPLAIN  SELELCT...
```

so you have a better inside what mysql has done with your query

Comment: I saw explain and this use `published_at` index for both query

Comment: i didn't expsect nothing else, that's why i explained why you see other runtime